# Expand environment variables of Process.Start command using environment crafted for child

Tags: c#, environment-variables, exec, spawn

The [`Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables?view=net-5.0) will expand variables using the environment block of my process.

`Process.Start` accepts a `ProcessStartInfo` which has an [`EnvironmentVariables` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.environmentvariables?view=net-5.0) which configures the environment block of the new process.

How can I expand my command (executable filename and argument list) using the environment block prepared for the child, not the one belonging to the parent process?  [Modifying the parent environment temporarily is not an option](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20081211-00/?p=19873) because it is a process-wide resource and interferes with concurrent environment access which may be occurring in other threads.

Are my only options to reinvent the `ExpandEnvironmentVariables` wheel or pass my command through `cmd /c` (which implies additional escaping on quoted arguments)?

Comment: I don't see any other options either. In my opinion, reinventing the `ExpandEnvironmentVariables` wheel with an overload that accepts an `EnvironmentVariables` parameter would be the lowest hanging fruit. I looked at the [.NET reference implementation for it](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/environment.cs,9c2cfdd656c7b3b6) and it's not terrible to implement. Most of the complexity is in looking up the environment variables from the Win32 API with the proper permissions, which would not apply to your overload. Mainly just make sure to follow their greedy match algorithm.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: Unfortunately the reference implementation is rather short because it delegates all the heavy lifting to the `ExpandEnvironmentStrings` API function in kernel32.dll.  That function isn't doing just environment variable lookup, but also identifying substitution codes inside the input string (*while respecting quoting* which is by far the most difficult part) and performing the replacement.  The loop fishing variable names out of the string doesn't actually have to be correct, since false positives make the security check overly strict, not a vulnerability.

Comment: @Partick However, there does appear to be a serious TOCTOU vulnerability in the .NET reference implementation that could lead to unauthorized information disclosure... the comment indicates that the programmer considered "some environment variable might be changed while this function is called" but failed to consider "some environment variable might be *created* while this function is called" or its implications for the accuracy of the `EnvironmentPermissionAccess.Read` demand.

Comment: Consider running on the input `%MIGHTBECREATED%VARICANREAD%WHATIWANNASTEAL%`.  The first loop will return the list of variables as `VARICANREAD` but if `MIGHTBECREATED` is created before the calls on line 532, instead of getting back `%MIGHTBECREATEDboringWHATIWANNASTEAL%` which passed the security check, the final result is `shinynewnessVARICANREADsupersecret`.  oops!